# Windows 7 - Find some certain Network Adapter Details

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

So, I know I should not ask about homework, but really my mind is blown by how the searches turn up nothing. I have a certain assignment that asks the following:

Using the graphical interface find and write down:
1. The name of the network adapter.
2. The speed of the connection.
3. The MAC address.
4. The manufacturer of the network adapter.
5. The version of the driver and the name of the file.

As far as 1 matters I used Device Manager and I am fine with it. For 4 same goes, quite easy. Also 5 is pretty much done (I am not sure on the file name, if someone can confirm it please). Now the problem lies with 2 and 3. I checked every detail known to man (and my computer) in the details tab of the network adapter. I found nothing! And I need to find this info in the properties of the network adapter somewhere. Google sent me to cmd which is another assignment alltogether, so I really need to extract the info from there. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open up a command prompt (Windows Key + R, then type CMD and hit enter) and then on the command prompt type ipconfig /all, look the for interface you are curious about and find the "Physical Address" aka the MAC Address. As for the speed of the connection, you can go to the Network Connections and right click the adapter and select Status, and by the Speed it will have what you are looking for. OR if you open up Task Manager and go to the Networking tab, it will also list the link speed.

Comment: I clearly stated I have to dig the info from the Device Manager, not cmd, the cmd part is another assignment that (I think) I can do. The Speed part, though, is helpful but I think it wanted me to get this from the network adapter properties, which seems quite impossible, so for now this stands as a solution to this at least.

Comment: Device Manager, or GUI? If you right click the adapter, and select Status, and then click the Details button it will give you the Physical Address in a graphical format. I am referring to Control Panel --> Network and Sharing Center, and then clicking on the Change Adapter Settings in the top left hand corner.